# Restore elasticsearch documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0

first to say: I use `elasticsearch 2.0` and had installed the `delete-by-query plugin`.

With this plugin I deleted a part of my documents. After this delete the documents are flagged as deleted and you can't find them anymore. To delete the documents from the disk, you must use `optimize` or `forcemerge` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20608417/elasticsearch-how-to-free-store-size-after-deleting-documents).

I don't delete the documents from disk. My problem is, after some days I recognized that I deleted some importend documents.

So my **question** is: can i restore the flagged documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you *can not* restore the flagged documents.

You don't have to call `forcemerge` to make sure documents are deleted from disk ( It is basically used to optimize index i.e if you have lot of segments then you call `forcemerge` to reduce the number of segments and make search faster. Another use case is if you delete lot of documents and want to reclaim disk space quickly, then you call `forcemerge`)

Documents `marked deleted` will be removed from disk as [`segment merging`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html) process is going on in background.

You could also check how many deleted docs you have with [`indices segments api`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-segments.html)

[This blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucenes-handling-of-deleted-documents) will help you a lot in understanding deletion process of ES